# VS Code Emmet is not showing up when it is activated

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Emmet abbrevations in html are not working for me.
Abbrevations like button#submit, div.menu, etc. are not working.
VS Code intelliscience also feels to be not working. I don't know in what manner its not working but I feel it isn't working right. It has become, ummm...., more.... in-accurate (I'm sorry, I can't describe it in words)

I tried many methods including:

1. Adding `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "html" }` into my settings.json file but it gives me this error: `Unknown Configuration Setting`
2. Uninstalling from the control panel and then re-installing it from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

What else should I try, please help me...

Comment: check the editor tab's language mode. There's a language mode indicator at the bottom right of the screen. **what does it say for you?** If it doesn't say what you expect, click it and select what language mode you want in the menu that appears. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It says the language I want it to say, HTML @starball